# Adding a NEW LINE character in between variables

Tags: variable, ksh, newlines

How can I add a new line character (\n) between two Unix variables?

I tried the following but it's getting printed in a single line instead of separate lines.

```
h=hello
w=world
c="$h"$'\n'"$w"
echo $c
Output: hello world
```

Comment: Related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/237982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works but you must quote `$c` in your echo statement for it to expand the way you want.

Like this:

```
h=hello
w=world
c="$h"$'\n'"$w"
echo "$c"
```

However this is almost certainly an x-y problem.  What do you ultimately need to accomplish?

As is it would be much better to just do:

```
h=hello
w=world
printf '%s\n' "$h" "$w"
```

---

Alternatively you can use the `-e` option to echo:

```
h=hello
w=world
c="${h}\n${w}"
echo -e "$c"
```